# In computing least squares why add vector of ones?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression

Reading the scipy least squares documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html states :

> We can rewrite the line equation as y = Ap, where A = [[x 1]] and p =
>   [[m], [c]]. Now use lstsq to solve for p:
>
> A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
>
> A array([[ 0.,  1.],
>          [ 1.,  1.],
>          [ 2.,  1.],
>          [ 3.,  1.]])

Why rewrite line as `y = Ap` and add vector ones to new variable `A` . Least squares estimated from x , y values alone so why add vector of ones ?

Comment: Any chance that the vector of ones is a weighting vector? For example, a weight of 2 would be the equivalent of having two instances of the same x, y pair, but non-integer values such as 1.5 can also be used for weighting the values.

Comment: It's not a weighting vector. Check my answer below. It's just a vector of pre-factors of the offset (constant) `c` which in `y=mx + c` = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have 5 x-values and corresponding 5 y-values which you want to fit via a linear regression. You can write then `y1=m*x1 + c`, `y2=m*x2 + c`, ... `y5=m*x5 + c` where `m` is the slope of the linear fit and `c` is the y-intercept (y-value for `x=0`). Representing this is a matrix form, since you have 5 x-values, your `A` matrix will have 5 rows with each row having two entries: x-value and constant `1` coming from the above mentioned set of 5 equations. Hence in `A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T`, you add as many ones as x-values using `np.ones(len(x))`. The introduction of a vector of ones is simply a result of usual matrix representation of a set of equations.

For getting more intuition, just write 5 equations I mentioned below each other and just re-write them in the matrix form and you will see why you need a vector of ones in `A`.

Comment: I note that this is implied in most polynomials such as a straight line "y = a * x^0 + b * x^1" or a quadratic "y = a * x^0 + b * x^1 + c * x^2" because x^0 = 1.

Comment: Yes, it’s just 1*c or you can also write x^0*c